# Смысл событий C#

Tags: c#, события

У меня есть пример использования события.

```
class ClassCounter
{
    public delegate void MethodContainer();
    public event MethodContainer onCount;

    public void Count()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (i == 71)
            {
                onCount();
            }
        }
    }
}
class Handler_I
{
    public void Message()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Пора действовать, ведь уже 71!");
    }
}
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ClassCounter Counter = new ClassCounter();
        Handler_I Handler1 = new Handler_I();

        Counter.onCount += Handler1.Message;
        Counter.Count();
    }
}
```

Но если убрать "event", то всё будет работать. Тогда в чём смысл event'а?
Или по-другому: В чём различие использования события и просто делегата?

Comment: Что в доках пишут про ключевое слово `event?

Comment: Лет 5 пишу на C# и ни разу не задавался [этим вопросом](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/event), просто умею использовать события и знаю, как работают. У вас сейчас один обработчик `Message()`. Попробуйте повесить `+=` на событие еще один обработчик, или тот же, но еще один раз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

События в C# - эдакая надстройка над делегатами. Если конкретнее - просто список делегатов (Delegate.Combine), к которому добавляются кое-какие изменения.
Смысл событий в том, что они созданы для безопасного и удобного использования в контексте ООП.
Значимые отличия событий от делегатов:

1. Список событий можно редактировать только с помощью += и -=, или, если переопределить их, add и remove (похоже на get,set).
2. Потокобезопасноть этих операторов (**с большой оговоркой**).
3. Событие можно вызвать только из самого класса.
4. Инкапсуляция (?)
5. Удобство использования.

Comment: Дал ответ на свой же вопрос спустя 3.5 года) И такое бывает

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте это запустить с event и без event

```
 class ClassCounter
    {
        public delegate void MethodContainer();
        public MethodContainer onCount;

        public void Count()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                if (i == 71)
                {
                    onCount();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    class Handler_I
    {
        public void Message()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Пора действовать, ведь уже 71!");
        }
        
         public void Message1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Давай давай!");
        }
        
         public void Message2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ну же!");
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClassCounter Counter = new ClassCounter();
            Handler_I Handler1 = new Handler_I();

            Counter.onCount += Handler1.Message;
            Counter.onCount += Handler1.Message1;
            Counter.onCount = Handler1.Message2;
            Counter.Count();
        }
    }
```

У событий нельзя взять и всех подписчиков заменить на другого одной строкой.
Зачем это нужно? Это всё ООП , вопрос для любителей пофилософствовать

Answer (score 0):

я думаю, что когда мы используем слово event то тогда мы  можем создать список методов, которые будут выполнятся при наступления этого события с помощью +=. Но если мы используем просто один делегат то  тогда мы просто можем подписаться на один метод.

Comment: Нет, не верно, в делегат можно тоже засунуть несколько методов

Answer (score 0):

В документации написано так:

> События представляют собой специальный вид многоадресного делегата,
> который можно вызвать только из класса или структуры, в которых он
> объявлен.

То есть событие не может быть инициировано откуда-то снаружи, и это хорошо для безопасности. Когда ты подписываешься на событие, то можешь быть уверен, что оно будет вызвано именно тем классом, на событие которого ты подписался, а не каким-то совершенно посторонним кодом.